# How can I get the filename of an uploaded file with GAE?

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, upload, filenames

I just upload it to the db (coming from a user request) like this:

```
 x.file = db.Blob(self.request.get("img"))
```

How do I get the filename, I have both the request and the blob, any solution that could be applied for any of them is ok for me

Answer (score 2):

The object that is returned by `self.request.get("img")` will have a property called `filename`. Assuming that "img" is a file upload, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the BlobInfo returned by BlobstoreUploadHandler
as described here
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.html 
it has a filename attribute as described here
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass.html